# add json data in csv file to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

i have a csv file with json data like below now i want to read it out to add to the database can anyone tell me ?

I just made it here, but I have a little problem that I can't get the data in the csv file

I am using asp.net core to write.

Can someone help me?

```
  path = Path.Combine(webRootPath + path);
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            string folder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), filename);
            if (Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                RemoveFolder(folder);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }

            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                BadDataFound = arg => Stc_baocao.Add(arg.Context.Parser.RawRecord),
                Delimiter = ",",
                HasHeaderRecord = true, 
                HeaderValidated = null,
                MissingFieldFound = null
            };
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {
                IEnumerable<objSTC_BAOCAO> records = csv.GetRecords<objSTC_BAOCAO>().ToList();

            }
```

```
{
"objSTC_BAOCAO":{
"VMABC":"01",
"NTENBAOCAO":"Báo cáo test 01",
"VTENMAUQD":"MBC01",
"ISUDUNG":true,
"NMOTA":"Ố zề",
"ACTIVE":1.0,
"VLAP":null
},
"objSTC_MAUBC":{
"MA":"MBC01",
"TEN":"mẫu báo cáo 01",
"TENREPORT":null,
"FUNCTION":"t",
"TEMPTBL":null,
"SUDUNG":true,
"PHANLOAI":null,
"SAPXEP":"e",
"DKLOC":null,
"SUMCOL":null,
"KHOGIAY":"A4*",
"ISCHITIEU":null,
"PSLK":"0",
"NHOMBC":0.0,
"NGUONDL":"100",
"DKGROUP":null,
"ANHMOTA":null,
"NIENDO":0.0,
"KIEUTONGHOP":null
},
```

Comment: What does the CSV file look like? What you posted is just a JSON snippet, not a CSV file. It shows part of an array of JSON objects, each one different than the previous one.

Comment: this is the data contained in my csv file and i want to read it out to add to the database

Comment: That's not CSV. That's a JSON snippet. CSV means Comma Separated Values. It's a text file where each line is a record and the fields Values are Separated by Commas, ie `Bananas,13,14.5,2022-01-01`

Comment: but it is saved in csv . file

Comment: What does your file *really* look like? What do the first two lines look like? I suspect you have a JSON file but it's unclear if the contents are a proper JSON array, ie starting `[` and ending with `]` or if one JSON object is stored per line. If you have a proper JSON file, `File.OpenRead` is all you need to read the file and `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` to deserialize it

Comment: `but it is saved in csv . file` and what you posted isn't a CSV file. `CSV` isn't some kind of binary format, It's just a plain old text file with values separated by commas. The extension doesn't matter. Only the contents